# VLC Application can read 360 degree video bit not the C code instance

Tags: c, vlc, libvlc

I have been trying to read a 360 degree video with a vlc instance and it just is not working.

The application itself can read the file but not when I use the code below ( by not reading, I mean I cannot drag the video and change viewpoints when I use the code below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include </usr/include/vlc/vlc.h>

int main(int argc , char **argv)                                
{
  libvlc_instance_t *instance;
  libvlc_media_player_t *mediaplayer;
  libvlc_media_t *media;
  
  instance=libvlc_new(0,NULL);

  media=libvlc_media_new_path(instance,"playlist/360_video.mp4");

  mediaplayer=libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(media);
  libvlc_media_release(media);

  libvlc_media_player_play(mediaplayer);
   
  sleep(60);

  libvlc_media_player_stop(mediaplayer);

  libvlc_media_player_release(mediaplayer);

  libvlc_release(instance);  
  return 0; 

}
```

My guess is that the instance cannot properly read the projection of the video as equirectangular that's why it display a rectangular projection.

Comment: I think you need to implement the mouse drags yourself, and update the viewpoint accordingly using the libvlc_video_update_viewpoint API, you don't get this functionality for free.

Comment: @caprica yeah , I have realized that later and was able to implement it. Thanks